# Is there an easier way to select every column but one in a table with a query in Access 2016?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table with many column such like Name, Country, Gender, ID etc. Is there an easier way to do select every column of this table within a query except the Gender column?

Comment: Easier as opposed to what? Are you using SQL or the GUI?

Comment: I use both. Easier as opposed to select every single column one by one (I have a loooot of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Shift+Click to select all fields in the GUI, then either Ctrl+Click to deselect the ones you don't want before dragging them down or delete the columns once you drag them down.

For aliases just add the alias with a colon before the column name like this:

Sex: Gender